# Is R a resource-hungry language?

Tags: r, resources, bigdata

I've heard from many people that **R** is built for processing petabytes of data; however, on the other hand, I'm hearing very often as well that if you want to process for example 8 GB of data, you'd better to have at least 8 GB of memory, otherwise you'll face some problems.

My question is if I need to process like 20 GB of data (which I think is fairly common in many projects), how much `Memory` and also `Processor` do I need? If you had any previous experience I'd be happy to know how it should be for 2 petabytes of data as well.

Comment: I think you can't process 2 petabytes of data with any language at once. Paraller solutions or processing in smaller pieces is needed. Check also : http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html

Comment: @Hemmo Thanks, by the way I think you can post it as an answer as well. :)

Comment: not if you know what you're doing.  with R's new [MonetDB.R package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MonetDB.R/), a crappy old laptop and `1GB` of RAM will outperform a fast SAS server.

Comment: @AnthonyDamico Nice! That is a advanced example of processing in smaller pieces right? You do not load everything in R, but you somehow refer to pieces of the external database?

Comment: @Hemmo zactly. no statistical language is as good at processing big data as professional databases are.. but `R` connects to those external databases easier than the rest :)

Comment: @AnthonyDamico Thanks! I still didn't have time to check that but will manage to check it ASAP. BTW, could you please post your comment as an answer also, thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can't process 2 petabytes of data with any language at once (well maybe with some specific software and/or hardware you could). Paraller solutions or processing in smaller pieces is always needed. In R, objects are stored in the virtual memory, so there's a clear limit how much data you can have in R at the same time. Check [Memory Limits in R](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html).